# how does arcmap calculate scalebar inside a WGS84 layout?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, cartography, scale

ArcMap lets you put a scalebar inside a layout referncing a WGS84 data frame.
How is the scale calculated? Is it a "mean" scale? And, in case it's right, what "mean" scale could mean?

Answer (score 5):

It is the scale at the equator.

Comment: +1 I was able to confirm this by creating a long horizontal window and panning vertically within it, going from south pole to north pole.  The scalebar never changed and gave correct distances at the equator.

Comment: Thanks a lot.
QuantumGIS uses the Harvesine formula calculated at the middle latitude of the mapcanvas extent. It's a much better aproximation.

I see many map printings in geographical CRS (strait lon/lat grids) with metrical scalebars. It's nonesense, besides ArcMap caluclates that scalebar as if it was on the Equator!

Comment: Not quite nonsense: the scale varies with orientation.  In the north-south direction, ArcMap's scale is correct at any latitude.  The QGIS solution is a compromise but arguably is not any more correct.